# Things he knew were not true, he knew could not be true

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, ellipses

> [*Things he knew were not true, he knew could not be true*.](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=669&t=27722)

Is this a grammatical sentence?

I don't really know what material has been ellipted, so a bracket analysis would help.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a grammatical sentence?

It is in the original form... but you have been lazy, and not quoted the whole, and the punctuation could be improved:

> He argued things he knew were not true - he knew could not be true.

The "full" version would be:

> He argued things *that* he knew were not true, *and* he *argued things that* he knew could not be true.

This is the transitive use to to **argue**:

OED

> **5.** transitive. **To bring forward the reasons for or against (a proposition, etc.); to discuss the pros and cons of; to treat by reasoning, examine controversially.**
>
> a1513   R. Fabyan New Cronycles Eng. & Fraunce (1516) I. lxxxxix. f. xxxix   *The sayd causes warre well and sufficiently argued.
> *
> 1883   Marquis of Salisbury Speech in Lords 17 July   *I do not see that it is my business to argue the legal considerations adverted to.*

Answer (score 1):

> He argued things he knew were not true, he knew could not be true.

The most obvious meaning of this sentence seems to be the following.

> He showed that among the things that he knew there were some that were untrue and he knew that they could not be true, ie, that there was no possibility for them to be true. This is not a grammatical sentence, but it takes only the addition of "they" to make it correct (colloquial): there is no subject for the verb "to be". The ellipsis of "that" is common in informal style.

- He argued things he knew were not true, he knew **they** could not be true. (colloquial)
- He argued that things that he knew were not true, he knew that they could not be true. (formal)

The coordination is paratactic, ([parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis)): in this sentence a simple comma is used.

Comment: Is the second _that/which_ after the comma here optional if we don't add a subject _things/they_ after the comma ?

Comment: @GJC As I understand this sentence it seems impossible to not to have a subject for "to be"; the reason is that there are two conjugated verbs and only one subject (he). If you consider "that" as a demonstrative, then it is a subject, but a demonstrative seems to have no evident antecedent in "things".